# RMBP 2013 and forcing windowed games in Low Resolution Mode

Tags: command-line, macbook-pro, resolution

Is it possible to launch a program without an associated `.app` bundle with the `Open in Low Resolution` mode activated? I am talking about `~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/dota\ 2\ beta/dota_osx` which is a `Mach-O executable i386`

For that matter command-line `mplayer` would also qualify.

Comment: Is the Low Resolution Mode checkbox on the Get Info pane greyed out?

Comment: Only `.app` files have that option. For example, if you `Show Package Contents` within the `.app` and navigate to `Contents/MacOS/blah-blah` where `blah-blah` is the binary, you'll have no such checkbox in its info panel.

Comment: I see what you mean - I'll have to have a play.